# Write row in google sheet using a dict

Tags: python, google-api, gspread

The documentation on inserting a row using gspread indicates it needs a list:

```
sheet.insert_row(row, index)
```

where row is a list, and index is the sheet row number.
But you can read a google spreadsheet into a list of dicts using get_all_records(). Is it possible to write to the sheet using a dict?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
kwargs = {'row': [my_list_of_data], 'index': some_integer}
sheet.insert(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Nope. What I meant was instead of: sheet.insert(row,index) where row is ["one", "two", "three"], to insert {"name" : "one", "address" : "two", "phone": "three"} where the keys are the column headers.